# Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE, : arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 588

Tags: r, api, jsonlite

I'm trying to work with an API from the NS (Dutch train company). I want to have it in a dataframe format but I get this error when I run the following code:

```
NSspoorkaart <- GET("https://gateway.apiportal.ns.nl/Spoorkaart-API/api/v1/spoorkaart", 
                    add_headers("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key" = "f354d5839ec5454fbaf1bc44304b1845"))

JSON <- fromJSON(content(NSspoorkaart, "text"), flatten = TRUE)
Data_NS <- as.data.frame(JSON)
```

Can someone explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this work?

```
NSspoorkaart <- GET("https://gateway.apiportal.ns.nl/Spoorkaart-API/api/v1/spoorkaart", add_headers("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key" = "f354d5839ec5454fbaf1bc44304b1845"))

NSspoorkaart.string <- content(NSspoorkaart, as = "text", encoding = "UTF-8")
NSspoorkaart.list <- jsonlite::fromJSON(NSspoorkaart.string)
NSspoorkaart.df <- NSspoorkaart.list$payload$features
```